# How to combine button and text field using SWT

Tags: java, swt, textfield

How to combine button and text field using SWT and also give a customized icon for the button.

Many have suggested to use Combo but it gives drop down option, but I don't want it to be a drop down icon. Can any one help here and suggest an implementation strategy?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say combine? Do you simply want them to always appear next to each other or do you want something similar to bootstrap's input group?

Comment: @Baz  : there is a label name , next comes the textfield where we enter the data , inside the text field i want a button with image without border.when we place the cursor on the text field , button should get highlighted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the best approach would be to use a `Composite` to group `Text` and `Label` objects.

The `Text` object is obviously your text field, and with the `Label` you can set an image to give a nice border-less button.

[image]

*Depending on your needs, this can be easily extended to allow for a multi-line text area, but I'll stick with a single line for the example*

```
public class TextWithButtonExample {

    /**
     * Simple class to accomplish what you want by wrapping
     * the Text and Label objects with a Composite.
     */
    public class TextWithButton {

        public TextWithButton(final Composite parent) {
            // The border gives the appearance of a single component
            final Composite baseComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
            baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
            final GridLayout baseCompositeGridLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
            baseCompositeGridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
            baseCompositeGridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
            baseComposite.setLayout(baseCompositeGridLayout);

            // You can set the background color and force it on 
            // the children (the Text and Label objects) to add 
            // to the illusion of a single component
            baseComposite.setBackground(new Color(parent.getDisplay(), new RGB(255, 255, 255)));
            baseComposite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);

            final Text text = new Text(baseComposite, SWT.SINGLE);
            text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

            // Get whatever image you want from wherever
            // (in this case the web so it can be run easily!)
            Image buttonImage;
            try {
                buttonImage = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(new URL("http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/ovr16/clear.gif")).createImage();
            } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
                buttonImage = null;
            }

            final Label button = new Label(baseComposite, SWT.NONE);
            button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true));
            button.setImage(buttonImage);
            button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent e) {
                    // Do whatever you want when the 'button' is clicked
                    text.setText("");
                }
            });
        }

    }

    final Display display;
    final Shell shell;

    public TextWithButtonExample() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        new TextWithButton(shell);
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.setSize(200, 100);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new TextWithButtonExample().run();
    }

}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the input.. I tried implementing this, But there is a gap between label and the text field.

Comment: ,Thanks for the input.. I tried implementing this, But the label image which I have set comes outside text field, i.e next to text field with a gap.How do I solve this? I don't want any gap, it should appear as though it has been embedded inside the text field.Thanks in advance

Comment: @Lisha You cannot place a [Label widget](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FLabel.html) (or any other widget for that matter) inside a [Text widget](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html). `it should appear as though it has been embedded inside the text field` - does the screenshot I attached in my answer not satisfy what you are looking for?

Comment: @Lisha `But the label image which I have set comes outside text field, i.e next to text field with a gap` - just to elaborate, what you're describing is the workaround that I present. By using a border on the parent composite, as well as common background colors you can achieve the illusion that they are one component.

Comment: I shall try this Common Background option, Thanks a lot

Comment: Can we add hover text also when we hover on the label which has the image , how do we implement that.?

Comment: @Lisha yes, take a look at the `setToolTipText` method that the `Label` class inherits

Comment: ,... This worked for me .... need one more clarification ... can we add a text and image (both on the either side of the table column). What i Mean is, if there is a table , i need header for that on the left and image on the right side of the same column. And the same for table cells.

Comment: @Lisha are you referring to a [Table](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTable.html) widget? If so that seems unrelated to this question and should be a separate question if you're having trouble making it work.

Comment: I have added a new question , could you please help me there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583127/how-to-add-image-on-the-right-side-of-the-table-column-and-table-cell-using-swt

Comment: @Lisha I can take a look. Also, please consider accepting this answer if you feel that it has completely answered your original question.