# How to add image on the right side of the table column and table cell using SWT in java

Tags: java, image, widget, swt

How do I add image to the right side of the table column retaining the Text to the left.
below is the code

```
TableColumn tc = new TableColumn(this.table_for_list, SWT.LEFT);
tc.setText("List");

for (int i = 0, n = this.table_for_list.getColumnCount(); i < n; i++) {
    this.table_for_list.getColumn(i).pack();
}        

TableItem item = new TableItem(this.table_for_list, SWT.NONE);
item.setText(0, "List 1");

TableItem item2 = new TableItem(this.table_for_list, SWT.NONE);
item2.setText(0, "List 2");
```

Table Column Header has "List" on the left side, now I want to add images on the other end (Right side end of the table).
I should be able to add in each row images on the right side of the table cell.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the image. Also, could you include some code as a starting point for what you've tried so far?

Comment: @avojak    I was unable to add image as it required 10 reputations .

Comment: @Lisha Upload it somewhere and post the link here.

Comment: http://imgh.us/tableColumn.png ..... This is the link for the image, i want images on the right side as shown as black squares in the link. in place of black squares i would like to add an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modifier [this snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet230.java) to get it to do what you asked for:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Image image = display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_INFORMATION);
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Images on the right side of the TableItem");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    int columnCount = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Column " + i);
    }
    int itemCount = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    }
    /*
     * NOTE: MeasureItem, PaintItem and EraseItem are called repeatedly.
     * Therefore, it is critical for performance that these methods be
     * as efficient as possible.
     */
    Listener paintListener = event ->
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SWT.MeasureItem:
            {
                Rectangle rect1 = image.getBounds();
                event.width += rect1.width;
                event.height = Math.max(event.height, rect1.height + 2);
                break;
            }
            case SWT.PaintItem:
            {
                TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
                Rectangle rect2 = image.getBounds();
                Rectangle bounds = item.getBounds(event.index);
                int x = bounds.x + bounds.width - rect2.width;
                int offset = Math.max(0, (event.height - rect2.height) / 2);
                event.gc.drawImage(image, x, event.y + offset);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    table.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, paintListener);
    table.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, paintListener);

    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }
    shell.setSize(500, 200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    if (image != null) image.dispose();
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: this worked for me , but images comes only when i set text for the rows i.e table items, Now i don't want to set text to the tables cells , but just want to display images at the right end of all the cells.  And one more issue ... Horizontal Span of the table has been set to 2, but the image comes right next to the last letter of the text ,instead i want the image to appear at the end of the cell. How can i add the same image to the Table Column(header).

Comment: @Lisha Alright, I updated the answer. As for the table column header: You're probaby better off asking that as a separate question once you've incorporated this answer.

Comment: This is not working , images come only when i set the text to table item

Comment: @Lisha The example I posted doesn't set text to the items and it still works.

Comment: not sure why , but its not working if i remove assigning  setText for table items.

Comment: @Lisha are you calling `pack()` on the columns?

Comment: Can we  add listener to this image ?

Comment: @Lisha You can, yes. But that would be a separate question and should be posted as such.